# Android POST always empty

Tags: php, android, database

My POST is always Null when I try to send something out from my android application. My goal is to send a pdf from my android application to the database but this is a totally different issue. I think my link is wrong but I am not certain enough. Right now I want to POST two variables and display one of them, the next step would be to save one of them in the database but I want to tackle the issue in baby steps.

What I forgot to add was when I tried to save it in the database and the result was the following.
[image: Database]

Android Application

```
  try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.at/kundenexecute.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
```

My Kundenexecute.php

```
   <?php       
     include "db.inc.php";
     include "redirect.php";
     session_start();


     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $data=$_POST['stringdata'];
     echo $id;
     ?>
```

Comment: This might simply be missing the correct `Content-Type` header. Try adding it, value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: This might sound idiotic but where should I add this, in the php or the android application?

Comment: On the Android side, as a request header. PHP needs to know which “format” you are sending the data in, otherwise it will not populate $_POST.

Comment: Like this?  httppost.addHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: I added the code in my application but nothing changed

Comment: `My POST is always Null`. ?? What is null? Dont understand a word.

Comment: Why is your Android app not reading the echo() from the php script? Why dont you echo() more? Echo some informative text. Ever heard of the php function isset()? Wel use it and echo() accordingly.

Comment: When I used POST to send something to save in my database the results always null, look at the picture I have put. I dont want to read the echo() from the php script in my app I want to parse information from my app to the php script and make a insert into with those.

Comment: Try and log the request headers in the PHP script - and then compare that to what headers you receive when you just use a normal HTML form to submit data to that URL.